# Semantically vague sentence

Tags: meaning, semantics

**That man is not to be trusted.**

Is this sentence semantically ok?i don't think the sentence is so straightforward.

(I found this word on Cambridge dictionary website)

Comment: Why is it not straightforward?

Comment: Because we can directly say"This man is not trustworthy. "

Comment: Yes, that is a paraphrase.  It is another way of expressing the same idea.  That's not a problem, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is fine semantically. In your comments you contrast it with "This man is not trustworthy", and I tend to agree with @James K, that they are pretty much equivalent. And even if that is the case, the fact that there are alternative ways of saying the same thing doesn't render any of those ways incorrect.

However, there could be a slight difference in the way people interpret the two versions. To my ears, the original:

> That man is not to be trusted

would best fit a situation where I have some reason to warn someone not to trust the man in question. By contrast:

> This man is not trustworthy

is less a recommendation and more a simple opinion about facts.
(I'm ignoring the fact that the first uses "That" while the second "This". That does modify the meaning further, but I'm assuming that difference was introduced unintentionally.)